# How to get value of parameter on URL on lightning community page?

Tags: lightning, url, parameters, lightning-community

I have URL in Lightning Community page, I want to get value of parameter from this ULR in Lightning.

https://www.testurl.com/page?accountRef=test123

How can I get value of accountRef?

I have tried with:

accountRef: {!v.accountRef}

The result is null.

I tried with [Getting the URL parameter into Lightning component using the "{! paramName}" expression](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165650/getting-the-url-parameter-into-lightning-component-using-the-paramname-exp)

Do we have any way if we don't want to use decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)) on controller js?

Comment: You declared <aura:attribute name="accountRef" type="String" />  ?

Answer (score -1):

If I use on app lightning builder, it worked for me
Here is example what I use on lightning app:

https://testurl.force.com/c/test.app?nameApp=Test

hello {!v.nameApp}