# Passing parameters to a Lightning Component inside a Lightning Tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, url, parameters

I created a lightning component that basically needs to receive an Account Id to work with, so when I was developing it, I created a standalone application and simply passed the accountId that I was using like this :

https://xxxxx.lightning.force.com/c/MyAwesomeApp.app?accountId=123456789

So now I need to put him inside a Lightning Tab, but I couln't find a way to pass my parameter there. After some search I found this code, but I think that this shouldn't be the way to handle it.

The url will be something like :

https://xxxxx.lightning.force.com/one/one.app?123456789amp;source=aloha#/n/MyLightningTab

(Where '123456789' is the ID that I need)

Then inside the 'doInit' (javascript controller), you need to get the parameter from the URL like this :

```
// This one gets you : '123456789amp;'     
var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1));
// This one gets you : '123456789'    
var tempVer=sPageURL.split('amp;');
```

(The topic where I found this code is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js))

Ok, fine, that works for now, but what if I need to pass more parameters in the future? How do I send parameters to my components that are inside a Lightning Tab?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK lightning does not provide support for this implementation, URL hacking is not allowed ( I would happy to be proven wrong). If you want to pass a parameter to your component from another component there are many ways like using aura:attribute/ aura:method or worst case go for window.postmethod to interact from 1 dom to another. Other members may also not recommend you going through URL hack route.

Comment: Hi @Swathi, I know that is not the correct way to handle it, but I don't have other lightning component on my scenario, so I can't use events and that kind of stuff. Still, I need to find a way to handle this...

Comment: where are you embedding this component?is it inside an account page record? or somewhere like a lightning tab?

Comment: @Swathi It is inside a lightning tab because I need to have the whole 'Salesforce Header' (if I can say on this way), so that's why I need it inside a tab. In order to make it work, I need to know who I am working with, that's why I need the parameter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no direct support for URL parameters in Lightning for components (only apps can receive parameters). Depending on specifics, there are two possible alternatives that might work.

---

For components meant to be shown on a record page, use [force:hasRecordId](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_interfaces_force_hasrecordid.htm). You'll automatically have an attribute `v.recordId` that you can use (no need to define it).

---

For components that need additional parameters, you typically use [force:navigateToComponent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToComponent.htm):

```
navigateToMyComponent : function(component, event, helper) {
    var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
    evt.setParams({
        componentDef : "c:myComponent",
        componentAttributes: {
            contactName : component.get("v.contact.Name")
        }
    });
    evt.fire();
}
```

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, thanks for this tips. Unfortunately I was imagining that there was no direct support for URL parameters when I tried to searched for it, but I try to handle my other components and use the force:navigateToComponent.

Comment: My team is grappling with this a bit. We have a use case where one Lightning page has to open a new window/tab and pass parameters to a Lightning component in that, but we still want the `one.app` container. The best I can come up with right now (2 undocumented "hacks" though) is to open a VF dispatcher page like `/one/one.app#/alohaRedirect/apex/VfDispatcher?param1=foo&param2=bar` and then have the VF page call `SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator.fireContainerEvent('force:navigateToComponent', {componentDef : "c:myComponent", componentAttributes: {param1: "foo", param2: "bar"}})`.

Comment: If `sforce.one` were to start supporting `navigateToComponent` then we'd be down to only one hack.

Comment: @CharlesT Yeah, I don't have a good answer to that at the moment; you might want to ask a new question and see if one of the other experts in our community can assist you.

Comment: @sfdcfox `force:navigateToComponent` is now deprecated in deference to using `lightning:navigation` on a component implementing `lightning:isUrlAddressable` (as of Summer '18, API 43.0). See the release notes [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_lc_components_navigation.htm).
See Ranga's answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165650/getting-the-url-parameter-into-lightning-component-using-the-paramname-exp) for an example

Comment: Use `const` not `var`!