# Salesforce community pages url authorization

Tags: community, customer-community, architecture, authorization, community-cloud

I am novice to salesforce, i have following usecase in my project developed using salesforce with vlocity.

1, restrict community users accessing URLs to community pages based on a flag (flag is coming from external API).

2, Hide or disable html element based on the flag.

Basically how to handle this kind of authorization in salesforce community (having number of lighting components and vlocity components)?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, please take some time to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the tour.
Once you have done so, make sure you include details of your problem (screenshots, steps to reproduce etc.) alongside with any errors you get when applied your solution.

Comment: Have a look at Audience Targeting https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.community_templates.meta/community_templates/community_builder_page_visibilty_overview.htm

Answer (score 0):

The method depends on the technology you're using. Here are 3 articles you can look at to determine how to get information from the URL into your code.

1. [Get URL Parameter of lightning component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165650/getting-the-url-parameter-into-lightning-component-using-the-paramname-exp)
2. [Get URL Parameter in Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000096gCIAQ)
3. [get URL parameter Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getParameters.htm)