# lightning:isUrlAddressable parameter disappears after reload

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I see some strange behavior with lightning:isUrlAddressable tab.
When I try to enter the parameter after loading the page immediately parameter is removed from the URL and component is not able to find the param value.

**Simple Cmp:**

```
<aura:component  implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable,force:appHostable" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="urlParam" type="string"/>
    <div class="slds-card">
        If you implements "lightning:isUrlAddressable" interface, then by 
        using v.pageReference,you can get URL params.
        <div class="slds-box">  
            Account name from URL parameter: <b>{!v.pageReference.state.accname}</b>
        </div>
    </div> 
</aura:component>
```

Screenshots:
[image]

**param is disappeared after pressing the ENTER button**

[image]

Comment: This works quite fine for me, try in some other browser?

Comment: Could be a Lightning Component Tab issue. Try addressing the component itself (as per [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation)), which will look something like: /lightning/cmp/c__myTestCmp?accname=Ajay.  Also see [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165650/getting-the-url-parameter-into-lightning-component-using-the-paramname-exp) for a full example

Comment: I tried in firefox browser too, it is same behavior.

Comment: @BrianMiller: Yes I tried your approach too, same behaviour, immediately after page load params are disappeared.

Comment: https://xxxxx--staging2.lightning.force.com/lightning/cmp/c__testCmp?accname=Ajay

Comment: Any answer? I am having same issue. the parameters disappear no matter how I try to load

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I found it in the document that we should add default namespace C__ to the parameters.

```
lightning/n/Test_Cmp?c__accname=ajay
```

This worked for me.

Comment: You add namespace to component names, not params.
Correct url should be `lightning/n/c__Test_Cmp?accname=ajay`

Comment: it doesn't work, I already tried, it says Enter a valid URL and try again. something has changes in Spring19.

Comment: Specifically this reference:
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_namespace_prefix_cruc_reminder.htm

Answer (score 2):

Well this is some fun stuff.
Although the documentation says you have to add "c__" to component name, I had the same issue when I didn't add "c__" to the param names.

For example:

```
https://<Instance>.lightning.force.com/lightning/cmp/c__CheckInCheckOut?step=123
```

Was loading the page without any parameter in the state variable.
See below the console.log of the pageReference:

```
{"type":"standard__component","attributes":{"componentName":"c__CheckInCheckOut"},"state":{}}
```

And the parameters after the "?" were not there anymore after load:

```
https://<Instance>.lightning.force.com/lightning/cmp/c__CheckInCheckOut
```

So I tried with both

```
https://<instance>.lightning.force.com/lightning/cmp/c__CheckInCheckOut?c__step=123
```

And that Worked.

```
{"type":"standard__component","attributes":{"componentName":"c__CheckInCheckOut"},"state":{"c__step":"123"}}
```

If anyone has an idea why it only works like that for me and seems to work another way for others i'd be curious to know.