# Mailchimp URL parameter disappears after landing to Lightning Tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, integration, authentication, mail-chimp

I need to authenticate Salesforce with Mailchimp. Through quick action, I am calling an aura component which then calls LWC component. I am able to login to Mailchimp from salesforce as per the login flow and get the required parameter 'code' in return. This param is used to get access token. The issue is URL changes after redirecting from Mailchimp to salesforce. [As mentioned in this link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251604/lightningisurladdressable-parameter-disappears-after-reload). Now I cannot pass 'c__' as mentioned in attached link since Mailchimp is passing it. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Sample URL return from Mailchimp: https://test-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/cmp/mailchimpAuthentication?c__code1=123123&code=973d078927935802edbeeb385b03a99b

After landing to lightning tab this is how URL looks like.
https://lightcloudcrm2-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/cmp/mailchimpAuthentication

Comment: After fetching the `c__` from `Mailchimp` how are you navigating to Lightning tab? **FYI:** `c__` works fine with no issues, we have a production org working with same flow.

Comment: Mailchimp is redirecting to lightning tab from redirect url.

Comment: Did you try named credential settings for this?

Comment: no. it is redirect url. I found the solution though. I used VF page's preview URL as redirect url. There I am able to get parameter. Thanks for your effort Nagendra!