# get URL parameter into lightning componet attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a url in lightning as follows:

> https://abc--progdev2.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/MyMembers?
>   c__caseId=500J000000K70ucIAB &c__claimId=M00103088
>   &c__legalOwnerName=Potomac%20Hospital%20of%20Prince%20William&c__endofUrl&ws=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FCase%2F500J000000K70ucIAB%2Fview%3Fc__srchFlow%3Dtrue

I want to get the value of the parameter case Id,claimId into a component attribute in the doInit event. Please Let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: please do some research on, there is already answer for this same questions

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165650/getting-the-url-parameter-into-lightning-component-using-the-paramname-exp

Comment: @Umesh, I saw the url and did the same. I am doing like this.  <aura:attribute name="caseId" type="String"/>. . Inside the doInit  event of the component I have as     component.get("v.pageReference").state.c__caseId). But I am getting an  error as follows "Cannot read property 'state' of null". Please let me know how I can resolve this

Comment: can you please update your Component and it's controller here by editing your questoin.