# Salesforce B2B Lightning - Creating a Direct Link to Product by ProductCode (SKU)

Tags: lightning, b2b

I'd like to create URLs in external applications that link directly to products on my Salesforce B2B Lightning site. The Product URLs are

```
https://www.mysalesforcesite.com/s/product/<slug>/<salesforce-guid>
```

Is there a way to link directly to a product using the SKU (ProductCode/External ID) value? My external systems know what the product SKUs are, but are not aware of the GUID that Salesforce generated for each product.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Given that there is no documentation that I can find on creating a link using the SKU, my educated guess is no - everywhere else, all links to object detail pages do so via the Salesforce Id of that record (the GUID you're talking about), so I don't think there's anything different here.  That said, you may be able to fashion a page in your community that makes use of a component which takes that SKU from a URL parameter, looks up the product and then redirects the user to the appropriate product page.  [This is an older thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165650/getting-the-url-parameter-into-lightning-component-using-the-paramname-exp), but may help lead you down the right path (the first answer does not appear applicable).  Full disclosure, I have not implemented nor tested this.