# Passing input variables to Salesforce Scheduler Inbound Guest User flow hosted in a website

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, integration, lightning-scheduler

I've implemented and modified Salesforce Inbound Guest User Flow to accomplish the business requirements following this guide:
https://goravseth.com/using-flows-as-a-form-tool-for-external-users

Essentially, so far I've created:

- A connected App;
- All the configs to allow guest users to make an appointment;
- A Visualforce page that will host the flow;
- An Aura:application that extends lightningOut (you can refer to the link above);
- The script to embed the VFPage/Flow into the website;

Everything would work perfectly fine, however, one of the requirements is such that: during the appointment process the website will provide to this "iframe" the email - like an input variable, and inside the flow, we will handle the logic to evaluate if this email is a Lead, an Account.

So what I am struggling with is how to pass the email from the website to the flow. I've done some investigation around that and tried to implement the suggestion explained in this post [Pass URL Variable to Flow contained in VisualForce Page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/370560/pass-url-variable-to-flow-contained-in-visualforce-page) , but still, it didn't work.
Any suggestion (with a simple example) on how can I pass the input variables from the website to the SF Scheduler Guest User Flow?

**Silly script that I used as Iframe on the website [Only for test purpose]:**

```
btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
    var emailResult = document.getElementById("emailInput").value;
    $Lightning.use("c:GuestAccessVFPage", function() { // Callback once framework and app load
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                "lightning:flow", // top-level component of your app
                {EmailInput : emailResult }, // attributes to set on the component when created
                "lexcontainer", // the DOM location to insert the component
                function(component) { // API name of the Flow
                    component.startFlow("MyInboundGuestUserFlow", inputVariables);
                }
            );
        }, 
        'https://MyOrg.force.com/abc' // Site endpoint
    );
});
```

**Aura app**

```
<aura:application access="global" extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess" >
    <aura:attribute name="EmailInput" type="String" description="this attribute is for Email passed from visualforce page"/>  
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" />
    <aura:dependency resource="lightning:flow"/>
</aura:application>
```

**VF Page**

```
<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:GuestAccessVFPage", function() {
        // Create the flow component 
        $Lightning.createComponent("lightning:flow", {},
            "flowContainer",
            function (component) {
                // Start an interview in the flowContainer div, and 
                //component.startFlow("MyInboundGuestUserFlow");
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

**.js**

```
({
    init : function (component) {
        var flow = component.find("flowData");
        var inputVariables = [
            {
                name    : 'EmailInput',
                type    : 'String',
                value   : component.get("v.EmailInput")
            }
        ];
        flow.startFlow("MyInboundGuestUserFlow", inputVariables);
    }
})
```

**Flow results**

[image: FlowResults]

I really appreciate any help you can provide.